# spring boot run in java CLI has a strange error that java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I build a spring boot project that start parent version is 1.4.2.RELEASE, it run successfully by eclipse, but when I run by java CLI, it occured a strange error, the command is `mvn clean package` and `java -jar target/yishi-service-0.5.0.war`

the exception is:

```
[main] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - StandardWrapper.Throwable 
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceConfigurationError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable: : java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry !/META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable not found in /tmp/jar_cache7985854176820315027.tmp
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.parse(ServiceFinder.java:512)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.access$400(ServiceFinder.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:572)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:418)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder.configure(ServiceFinderBinder.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:256)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jiajian.yishi.YishiServiceProjectApplication.main(YishiServiceProjectApplication.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
```

this embedded tomcat version is: 8.5.6.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have cross-posted the same question on the [Spring Boot issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7496) (please don't do that). It looks like a bug in Spring Boot as far as I can see so let's continue the discussion on the Spring Boot issue.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much!